# Unity Sprite Colors Wrong, But Compression Is None, And Filter Mode Is Point

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, colors, sprite, gimp

## Problem

I know that Unity sprites have compression and filtering applied.

I have already disabled this on the images.

See below.

[image]

I have edited these in `Gimp` and when I export and import them into `Gimp` the colors are

| Color | Hex |
| --- | --- |
| Light Blue | 0066aa |
| Blue | 0044aa |
| Dark Blue | 0022aa |
| Darkest Blue | 000088 |

See Below:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

When I import this into Unity it looks slightly off, and it makes no sense.

Side-by-side next to a separate image this is what it looks like.
The left one is the intended color. The right color is the one I'm getting on import.

[image]

If I take these images and import them into GIMP again, the colors are still reporting as correct. HOWEVER, if I take a picture of the Unity sprites and check the colors, they're completely incorrect.

| Color | Hex |
| --- | --- |
| Light Blue | 275e9b |
| Blue | 173f9a |
| Dark Blue | 081f9a |
| Darkest Blue | 00007b |

See images below
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

## Question

So what's the issue here.
It's obviously not compression.
It's obviously not filtering.
I can see that the colors for the source images are correct.
BUT, when they're imported and used in Unity the colors are dark and incorrect?

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

I have checked the image properties and it is using `GIMP built-in sRGB`

[image]

If I check the color management I see there are settings, but I'm not sure what is relevant or isn't.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: looks more like it doesnt think they are lit

Comment: Is there a color profile involved and what are you color management options in Gimp?

Comment: Could depend of OS night mode filter + screen capture software, e.g. ShareX screws like so.

Comment: @BugFinder can you elaborate on the lighting, are there specific settings I should be using?

Comment: @xenoid can you elaborate on the color management, what should I be looking for?

Comment: @aybe It is definitely not related to those as I don't use those features.

Comment: `Image > Image properties`: `Color profile` tab (anything not `sRGB`) and `Edit > Preferences > Color management`

Comment: @xenoid I have updated the post to include the information you have asked. Is there something I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shout out to @xenoid for solving this problem. The issue is that `GIMP` used something called `Color-managed display` that was somehow modifying this.

To fix this I ended up going to `GIMP` -> `Preferences` -> `Color Management` -> `Image Display Mode` and changing it from `Color-managed display` to `No color management`

[image]

This was also fixed by going to `Image` -> `Color Management` -> `Enable Color Management` and making sure that `Enable Color Management` does not have a checkmark on it.

[image]

I honestly have no idea what that feature is, or what it was doing, and to be honest, I'm a bit frustrated by `GIMP` as this is another experience with the tool that has demonstrated it making decisions on my behalf that I do not want.

Once again, thank you @xenoid for taking the time to help me identify this issue!

Comment: Don't be too quick to accuse Gimp. The color management in Gimp works. It is completely possible that the other side is not doing things properly.

Comment: Totally.   

Unity has always been a troublemaker for me.


But for now that's my scapegoat ;)